# regex which matches a word

Tags: php, regex

I need to be able to match a price value from a string given the string starts with `Shipping (UK):</span>`

**string**

```
Shipping (UK):</span>&#163;2.95
```

**regex so far**

```
(?<=\):<\/span>).*
```

I have tried to do something like this...

```
(?<=\Shipping (UK):<\/span>).*
```

but this does not work, what is the right way to construct this regular expression?

Comment: If you're just after the price value, can't you just search for that, with something like `\d+\.\d{2}`?

Comment: Great little online tool to check your regex syntax:
http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: @Charmander yes I realize that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis in your current regex [to get it to match:](http://regexr.com?31pbe)

```
(?<=Shipping \(UK\):<\/span>).*
```

Also, Charmander is correct, you don't want the shorthand `\S`, you want just `S`.

Comment: Ok that's great, I was putting the escape parenthesis in the wrong place, but why is there not an escape parenthesis before the string "Shipping"?

Comment: Because you only escape characters that have special meaning in regexes - Parenthesis create a capturing group, and you want to match the literal character parenthesis.